# Почему "наказанный" с двумя Н?

Tags: причастие

Почему *наказа**нн**ый* пишется всегда с двумя Н? Потому что есть приставка *на-*? Так нет слова *казанный*, и глагол *казать* уже не используется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что это причастие (страд. пр. вр. сов. вида), и по смыслу его нельзя трактовать как прилагательное (пареный и т.п.): факт подвержения действию наказания не является свойством. Это всегда "тот, кого наказали". Даже если это слово как существительное трактовать (в предложении это может быть подлежащим), форма причастия (как и значение слова) сохраняется.

Answer (score 1):

Это уж совсем элементарный вопрос, школьная программа. Страдательное причастие прошедшего времени, образованное от глагола совершенного вида.